# Possible to use flash in java application?

Tags: java, flash

I am writing an application in java and have a question. Is it possible for me to make buttons, etc... In flash, and make them call functions in my java application? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: Is it an application or an applet? Applets can communicate with javascript: [Invoking Applet Methods From Javascript Code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html). And I'm pretty sure Flash can call javascript functions, so you could write a layer between the two in javascript.

Comment: If only @Sardtok posted that as an answer instead of a comment, that's exactly what I needed!

Comment: Posted as an answer. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working on an applet, Flash can communicate with the applet via JavaScript, which has an interface for calling methods in Java Applets. It's also possible for an applet to call JavaScript functions, so it can work as a two-way wrapper. [Invoking Applet Methods from JavaScript](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html), and [Invoking JavaScript from Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingJavaScriptFromApplet.html).

Answer (score 1):

First of all we need to know what kind of java application you are talking about: A web application, a client server (swing, awt, swt, other gui framework), a mobile app, other kind?

Adobe Flex Builder already does it for web/ajax applications. Your view tier is flex/flash specific while your model, controller and database tiers are still java.

If you are talking about a client/server application I would say no - you can't - unless you use some kind of flash container at your view tier.

Comment: Well, there's also WebSockets which can be used for a Client/Server system. I think Flash uses WebSockets for its networking, but I haven't really done a lot of Flash. I have tried WebSockets to hook web pages to Arduino hardware, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a SOA based java solution can be called via ActionScript, alike Servlets can be called too via common HTTP POST (Flash or Javascript)